# Outlook 2010 Creating Folders and Subfolders

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have this code that creates a series of folders under the currently selected folder:

```
Public Sub CreateFolders()
Dim CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim List As New VBA.Collection
Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim Item As Variant

List.Add Array("Audio Video Graphics", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Close Out", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Correspondence", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Expenditure Adjustments", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Invoices", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Project Schedule", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("RADPARs and Contracts", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("REQs and POs", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Technical Information", olFolderInbox)

Set CurrentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set Folders = CurrentFolder.Folders
For Each Item In List
    Folders.Add Item(0), Item(1)
Next
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is add a subfolder called Proposal to be created under the "REQs and POs" folder.

This is being used to create folders on a public folder. I have never done coding in VBA before and cant for the life of me figure out how to add the subfolder.

I have been looking around online but can't find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
Public Sub CreateFolders()
Dim CurrentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim List As New VBA.Collection
Dim Folders As Outlook.Folders
Dim Item As Variant

List.Add Array("Audio Video Graphics", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Close Out", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Correspondence", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Expenditure Adjustments", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Invoices", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Project Schedule", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("RADPARs and Contracts", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("REQs and POs", olFolderInbox)
List.Add Array("Technical Information", olFolderInbox)

Set CurrentFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set Folders = CurrentFolder.Folders
For Each Item In List
    Folders.Add Item(0), Item(1)
Next

Set Folders = CurrentFolder.Folders.Item("REQs and POs").Folders

' or simply
'Set Folders = CurrentFolder.Folders("REQs and POs").Folders

Folders.Add "Proposal", olFolderInbox

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I was over thinking it this entire time.